# git cloning into a subdirectory

Tags: git, bitbucket, svn2git

I did an svn2git migration and need to place that newly converted local git into a subdirectory of a bitbucket repo.

So I have

```
svn2git/
```

and want it to be placed in my developer folder in bitbucket

```
stuff/svn2git
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think git cares about which directory it is in.  You should be able to just move it:

```
mv svn2git stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Copy it in, under the bitbucket repository and add it as part of it.
2. Create a separate git repository and add it as a remote under the existing bitbucket repository.

Information regarding remotes can be found at http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html‎ .

Answer (score 0):

You can directly move the local git folder to the desired location. 
As if git is initialized in the project folder, all the files inside it will automatically be tracked by git once it's been added.